# Using FormsAuthentication or using Session

Tags: asp.net

i'm coding my ASP.NET website
i have this question:
for Authentication a user 
which one is better and why ?

```
        if ((UserEmail.Text == "oli@yahoo.com") &&
    (UserPass.Text == "1"))
    {

        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage
           (UserEmail.Text, Persist.Checked);
          Response.Redirect("profile.aspx");

    }
    else
    {
        Msg.Text = "Invalid credentials. Please try again.";
    }
```

or

```
        if ((UserEmail.Text == "oli@yahoo.com") &&
    (UserPass.Text == "1"))
    {

        Session["ID"]=UserEmail.Text;
          Response.Redirect("profile.aspx");

    }
    else
    {
        Msg.Text = "Invalid credentials. Please try again.";
    }
```

please help me to select the correct form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If FormsAuthentication is set up correctly it will automatically redirect the user to the login page.  If you are doing it yourself, you will have to add code on all of your pages to make sure that the user is logged in.

Regarding security, I would call them equivalent as long as you are using SSL.  FormsAuthentication encrypts the user id and will save it in a cookie.  Session will just store the session ID in a cookie.

Comment: which one is more secure ?